# Convolution problem involving binomial

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

[image]

Do I have to use binomial theorem? Also how does 1 get in the limit of integrand?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(f * g) (t) &=& \displaystyle \int_0^t f(a) g(t-a) \ \mathrm da \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^t a^m (t-a)^n \ \mathrm da \\
&=& \displaystyle \int_0^t (ut)^m (t-ut)^n \ \mathrm d(ut) \\
&=& \displaystyle t \int_0^1 (ut)^m (t-ut)^n \ \mathrm du \\
&=& \displaystyle t \int_0^1 t^m u^m t^n (1-u)^n \ \mathrm du \\
&=& \displaystyle t^{m+n+1} \int_0^1 u^m (1-u)^n \ \mathrm du \\
\end{array}$$

where $a = ut$.

**Note**: The limits are $0$ and $t$ instead of $-\infty$ and $\infty$, because $f$ and $g$ are assumed to be only defined on $\Bbb R_{>0}$.